# How to make groups of all the Customers, Admins and Staff Members and render accordingly in same template based on URL hit?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to show all the Customers, Superusers and Staff members in a same template. How can I do this? I have a running code like this

```
class GroupListView(UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'admin_app/group_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        group_name = (self.kwargs['group'])
        if group_name == 'admin':
            context['user_list']= User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True, is_staff=True)
        elif group_name == 'staff':
            context['user_list'] = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
        else:
            context['user_list'] = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False, is_staff=False)
        return context

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
```

and the urls which produce hits are like this

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:group_list' group='admin' %}"><i class="fa fa-adn"></i>Admin</a>
```

Template is big so there is no need to post that. This is producing results but is there a better way to do this?

How can I make Groups and then render the data?

NOTE- How can I just make a link and view that will sort all the Users according to the link clicked. (same way in Django- Admin)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there's anything wrong with what you're doing already, especially given that it's working as you want. Is there some specific reason you'd rather not do it like this?

Comment: It looks like it is too much work. Codewill look messy if there are many groups

Comment: Ah, so you mean you're going to have more groups than just admin, staff and users?

Comment: @urbanespaceman yes! exactly. Can you help me with this problem of making url parameters optional/non-capturing?

Comment: @urbanespaceman ``` re_path(r'^users/(?:(?P<slug:sort_by>))', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user_list'), ```  How can I make this slug parameter optional/non capturing so that it won't matter if there is a slug present or not?

Answer (score -1):

When assigning users to [Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#groups) you can create as many groups as you like.

If you want to dynamically create urls for all groups and show a list of users belonging to that group you could do this:

To create the urls:
For example on your userListView add group to the context. Then in the get_queryset method you can check if the kwarg 'group' is available. If it is available you filter the queryset based on that.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class UsersListView(ListView):
model = User
template_name = 'user_list.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['groups'] = Group.objects.all()
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    try:
        group = self.kwargs['group']
        queryset = queryset.filter(groups=group)
    except:
        pass
    return queryset
```

then in your template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-md-10">
    <table>
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <tr><td>{{ object }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <table class="table">
      {% for group in groups %}
          <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'staff:user_list' group=group.id %}">{{ group }}</a></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

in urls.py you van add two routes to the same view:

```
path('users/', views.UsersListView.as_view(), name='user_list'),
path('users/<group>/', views.UsersListView.as_view(), name='user_list'),
```

Indentation is a bit off, but you get the point.

Comment: Just for future reference: you should use comments to clarify the question, not put in a non-answer as an answer ...

Comment: I know. "You must have 50 reputation to comment".

Comment: @Gijsthebookie yeah! that I know using GET method? but won't it require seperate urls? it'll make the urls look messy. I have tried that too. Can you tell me to make the  url parameters optional?

Comment: @Gijsthebookie  ``` re_path(r'^users/(?:(?P<slug:sort_by>))', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user_list'),  ```   make the slug field optional?

Comment: See updated answer. This is what you mean, right? Of course in this example it uses the django groups, instead of staff / superuser / regular user, because you said you want to create many groups.